# I want to use BoostQuery to promote certain results but I need a variable boost factor, is there a simple way to achieve this?

Tags: lucene

[rewritten for clarity]

I'm indexing and searching a library of documents. All documents have 'title, 'content', 'topic', 'category' and 'version' fields. As currently implemented the category and version are only involved in searching if the user explicitly tests them. The enhancement I wish to make will promote query results if the category matches a particular value, and will promote results with higher version numbers more than those with lower values.

A typical query does a text match on 'title' and 'content', and returns results ordered by Lucene's default scoring. I want to extend this so that results which match "category:relnote" are boosted, and they are boosted by a factor which is correlated with the value of the version field. But so far as I can see BoostQuery doesn't have this flexibility. So this is the best I have come up with:

```
public class SearchIndex(Indexreader reader, IndexSearcher searcher, String userQuery) {
   String field = "text";
   int max = reader.numDocs();
   try {
      Map<String, Analyzer> analyzerPerField = new HashMap<String, Analyzer>();
      analyzerPerField.put("version", new VersionAnalyzer());
      PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper analyzerWrapper = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new TechAnalyzer(), analyzerPerField);
      QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(field, analyzerWrapper);
      parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParserBase.AND_OPERATOR);

      BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
         .add(parser.parse(userQuery), Occur.MUST)
         .add(new BoostQuery(parser.parse("category:relnotes version:9*"), 90.0f), Occur.SHOULD)
         .add(new BoostQuery(parser.parse("category:relnotes version:8*"), 80.0f), Occur.SHOULD)
         .add(new BoostQuery(parser.parse("category:relnotes version:7*"), 70.0f), Occur.SHOULD)
         .add(new BoostQuery(parser.parse("category:relnotes version:6*"), 60.0f), Occur.SHOULD)
         .add(new BoostQuery(parser.parse("category:relnotes version:5*"), 50.0f), Occur.SHOULD)
         .add(new BoostQuery(parser.parse("category:relnotes version:4*"), 40.0f), Occur.SHOULD)
         .add(new BoostQuery(parser.parse("category:relnotes version:3*"), 30.0f), Occur.SHOULD)
         .build();

      TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, max);
      ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
      // and so on
      ...
   }
}
```

This approach is working after a fashion, but surely there must be a better way to boost the results than passing them through a chain of fixed boosters as in the sample above.

However I can't see how to vary the boost factor using a formula based on the evaluated 'version' value. Is it possible, and if so, how would I achieve it?

Incidentally, based on my reading I expected the boost factor to be relative (examples usually explain it as "a boost factor of 4.0f means that  query is four times as important as  query, etc.), but my experience testing different values suggests that the boost factor is just a number added to the score. Is that correct?

Thanks